# Find all proper subgroups of multiplicative group $\Bbb{Z}_{13}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Multiplicative group in $\Bbb{Z}_{13}$. Where multiplication is modulo $13$.

So the $G=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$ .

It must contain $1$ as the identity. I found the following three. Are there others ?

$H=\{1,3,9\};K=\{1,12\};L=\{1,5,8,12\}$

I can't find another.

Order of elements $(|2|=12), (|3|=3), (|4|=6), (|5|=4), (|6|=12), (|7|=12),\\ (|8|=4), (|9|=3), (|10|=6), (|11|=12),(|12|=2) $

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: Since $\Bbb{Z}_{13}$ is a field so its multiplicative group is a cyclic group $G=\langle a \rangle$ of order $12$ and for each divisor $k$  of $12$ there exist one and only subgroup of order $k$, namley $\langle a^{12/k} \rangle$

Comment: @Travis: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: So another would be 1,4,3,12,9,10

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar: First what is the generator for that multiplicative group? If you know that, then everything is easy!

Comment: Yeah I got it. I just seem to be having a bad day. This was extremely easy.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar: (sorry for the late reply) Yes! the another subgroup you mentioned is correct.  $\{1,4,3,12,9,10\}=\langle 2^{12/6} \rangle=\langle 2^2 \rangle=\langle 4 \rangle$