# List all of the subgroups of $(\mathbb Z_{11}\setminus \{[0]\}, \cdot)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So obviously the order of this group is $10$. Now I need to find a generator, so I can find the subgroups.
Since $3$ and $10$ are relatively prime, $3$ would be a generator for this group, right? And it would help with getting the subgroups?

Comment: $3^5\equiv1\pmod{11}$. You want a *primitive root* modulo $11$.

Comment: Okay. So a generator would be 2?

Comment: reference : (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973114/find-all-proper-subgroups-of-multiplicative-group-bbbz-13/2973115#2973115)

Answer (score 2):

Using the comments and your insight that $2$ generates $\Bbb Z_{11}^*$, we can say that for each $d$ such that $d\mid 10$, we have that $2^{\frac{10}d}$ generates a subgroup of order $d$.

Comment: No.  There are only $\varphi (10)=4$ generators.  They are $2,2^3,2^7$ and $2^9$.

Comment: @PerelMan that is, $2,6,7$ and $8$ are the only generators.  For instance,  $3$ has order $5$;  so it's not a generator.

Comment: Right @Chris I delete my false statement

Answer (score 0):

The element $-1=10$ surely generates a subgroup of order two, namely $\{1,-1=10\}$. Take another element, for instance $2$; then
$$
2^2=4,\quad 2^5=10
$$
OK, the subgroup generated by $2$ is the whole group. Therefore $2^2=4$ generates the only subgroup of order five.